# Postgres slow query joining first record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
    SELECT
      mt.market_coin_id AS coin_id,
      mt.quantity AS quantity,
      (ha.price_eur * mt.quantity) as test
    FROM
      market_transactions mt
    JOIN historical_data ha ON ha.id = (SELECT id FROM historical_data WHERE historical_data.coin_id = mt.market_coin_id ORDER BY mt.trade_at <-> snapshot_on LIMIT 1)
    WHERE
      mt.user_id = 1
```

what I'm trying to do is to calculate a price (`test`) on the fly by joining the historical pricing table on the first time record `historical_data.snapshot_on` that matches the transaction date `mt.trade_at`

however the query seems very slow.

assuming everything is pretty much indexed, is there a proper way to make this query a bit faster?

`historical_data`

```
ID    | COIN_ID | SNAPSHOT_ON | PRICE_USD | PRICE_EUR | 
------|---------|-------------|-----------|-----------|
42794 | 422     | 2017-07-31  | 0.0001353 | 0.0001152 | 
42795 | 422     | 2017-08-01  | 0.0001144 | 0.0000968 |
```

`market_transactions`

```
ID  | USER_ID | MARKET_COIN_ID | QUANTITY       | TRADE_AT
----|---------|----------------|----------------|------------------------
347 | 1       | 422            | 1463.36263314  | 2017-09-01 13:55:57
```

Comment: what do your tables look like?

Comment: What is the purpose of `mt.trade_at <-> snapshot_on`?  Based on your description, I don't see that it is necessary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's a method to fetch the first matching record in that table, the one that has `snapshot_at` nearest the transaction `trade_at`, to fetch the price of that day

Comment: @drum added example data and simplified the example

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . Why not just use `>=` or `<=` ?  Seems much simpler.

Comment: @GordonLinoff scouted around for some techniques how to perform such task and this is the result of what I found working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like this:

```
SELECT mt.market_coin_id AS coin_id, mt.quantity AS quantity,
       (SELECT ha.price_eur * mt.quantity
        FROM historical_data ha
        WHERE ha.coin_id = mt.market_coin_id AND
              ha.snapshot_on <= mt.trade_at
        ORDER BY ha.snapshot_on DESC
        LIMIT 1
       ) as test
FROM market_transactions mt
WHERE mt.user_id = 1;
```

Then you want indexes on `market_transactions(user_id, market_coin_id, quantity)` and `historical_data(coin_id, snapshot_on)`.

Comment: mm, this however won't find the first price snapshot if we have a trade done before that.

Comment: @JohnSmith . . . You might want to ask another question with sample data and desired results for this particular scenario.